# What does the u in a Django DateTimeField refer to?

Tags: django, django-models

In the source code for the DateTimeField (Python 3.8), it has the following error handling:

```
    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid': _('“%(value)s” value has an invalid format. It must be in '
                     'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.'),
        'invalid_date': _("“%(value)s” value has the correct format "
                          "(YYYY-MM-DD) but it is an invalid date."),
        'invalid_datetime': _('“%(value)s” value has the correct format '
                              '(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]) '
                              'but it is an invalid date/time.'),
    }
```

What is the `uuuuu` referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Microseconds. The symbol for "micro" (μ) looks a bit like a u, so they use that.

Answer (score 1):

If used in a string passed to a time formatter, the formatter would insert microseconds in place of `u` (see [this part of the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date)). Also, the number of `u`s determine the number of decimals inserted.

So in the case of these error messages, an error would be raised if the string passed to `DateTimeField` e.g. contained letters instead of digits where the microseconds part of the string is expected, or if too many decimals were included, etc.